# Android: make AsyncTask automatically update the progress according to the time the work would take

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I've read the documentation of `AsyncTask` but I just need to know is it possible to make the asynctask update the progress according to the time the work in `doInBackground()` would take to complete. For example, we have to delete a 2 GB file, if it takes 5 seconds to delete, asynctask should update the progress according to 5 seconds.

Comment: Do you know (programatically) how much time it will take?
What have you tried so far? Did you already use `publishProgress`?

Comment: Sounds like you rather need `Future` instead of `AsyncTask` because the AsyncTask really doesn't know when it will end.

Comment: we update `publishProgress` manually according to the steps we gotta perform, I just want the publishProgress to adjust the update value